# Extract JSON and save it in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Following is the my `JSON`, and i want to extract the data and save it to a `NSMutableArray`. However, this doesn't get extracted accurately. I am stuck with this for awhile now. Can someone help me out ?

Note: I want the `JSON` to be extracted as it is. With each sub category.

```
{  
   "Animal":[  
      {  
         "Dog":[  
            {  
               "id":"644"

            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "Cat":[  
            {  
               "id":"4125"

            },
            {  
               "id":"1326"

            }

         ]
      },
      {  
         "Mouse":[  
            {  
               "id":"224"

            },
            {  
               "id":"245"

            }
         ]
      },

      {  
         "Fish":[  
            {  
               "id":"144"

            },
            {  
               "id":"142"

            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to add these components to a NSMutableArray. How can i do this ?

```
animalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i =0; i < [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"Animal"]  count]; i++) {

            dictionary= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];




    for (int k =0; k < [[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"Animal"] objectAtIndex:i] count]; k++) {

       dictionary setObject:[[[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"Animal"] objectAtIndex:i]  objectAtIndex:k] objectForKey:@"id"]  forKey:@"id"];



    [animalArray addObject: dictionary];

    }



}
```

Comment: Do you want to cast it into a dictionary? or you want a specific format as in a specific structure in the resultant dictionary to be? If so, please mention the structure

Comment: The structure should be the same as the JSON.

Comment: Did you try enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ?

Comment: No, i have never heard it before. Can you show me how it is done. (Also i am googling how to use it)

Comment: Then y enumerate among all these objects?
Just cast the JSON to a NSdictionary?

Comment: @SahebRoy i Want to extract the data and save it in the same order. How can i do it ?

Comment: Check the answer and tell me if it works

Comment: you can try this to do enumeration : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414456/how-to-give-the-integer-key-value-for-dictionary/32414512?noredirect=1#comment52737940_32414512

Comment: as far as i know, by enumeration it would be easy and fast to get sub objects and store them in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get a NSDictionary object of exact structure that of the JSON

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData // this is your JSON
                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                    error:&jsonError];
NSLog(@"%@",json); // check the structure here
```

Comment: Yes, i want to extract the data, and save the `Dog`,`Cat`,`Mouse` and `Fish` seperately.

Comment: Plz implement this and check if it helps

Comment: I did. It gives the JSON result in a NSDictionary format. I already have this working. But, i want the sub catergories extracted `ex: Dog,Cat,Mouse and Fish`)

Comment: Yes but in what structure do you want it? if you want it in any other structure then mention it.. Or if you want to keep it as it is, then use the Dictionary for whatever you want the Structure to do directly, why bother ennumerating the structure when you are going to keep it the same

Answer (score 0):

I deep recommend use Mantle Library for parse JSON content:
[Mantle Lib](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle)

And here a good introduction tutorial how use this lib:
[How use mantle lib](http://substantial.com/blog/2014/05/20/parsing-json-in-ios-with-mantle/)

You will see how easy is parsing and use data latter , and question please fell free for ask